# Sum of arrays of objects withe pipe transform Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, pipe, reduce

I have list of objects with totaltime (there are other properties in objects

```
delayCount = { "delays": [ { "centre": "AAAA", "cause": "G - Capacity", "totalTime": 0 }, { "centre": "BBBB", "cause": "S - Staffing", "totalTime": 303 }, { "centre": "CCCC", "cause": "C - Capacity", "totalTi in arrayme": 34 } ] }
```

I am looking for smart pipe transform that would sum "totaTime", I used this code:

```
import { NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sum'
})
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: number[], attr: string): number {
    // @ts-ignore
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
```

and in the component HTML I used this :

```
    {{ delayCount$ | async | sum:'totalTime'}}
```

And I had this error :

```
Argument type ListCount is not assignable to parameter type number[]
```

PS: ListCount is model :

```
export interface ListCount {
  centre?: string;
  cause?: string;
  totalTime?: number;
}
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the data you have provided, there are two problems

1. You should pass "delays" field of your object

```
{{ (delayCount$ | async).delays | sum:'totalTime' }}
```

2. Adjust pipe to get the right type

```
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: string): number {
    // @ts-ignore
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
```

And do not use ts-ignore

Comment: I still have this error for ```attr``` type :
```error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ListCount'
```

Comment: Can you change this example to reproduce your error? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cwu82y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts